# Pick specific letters from string

Tags: sql-server

Could you please help me to pick highlighted information and display in Required column as per my image below. 
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than treating it as an "picking" (extraction) problem, since the areas before, between, and after each value are consistent, you can just use the replace function. Something like this:

```
SELECT reference,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( reference, 
    'course=',''),
    '&stream=None&plan=','-'),
    '&entity=COLLEGE', '') AS required
FROM mytable
```

It's a bit of a hack, but provided your data really are as consistent as they appear, it should work. If the URLs you are parsing differ in ways other than those two parameters, things will get more complex.

Answer (score 0):

using charindex() to find the position and substring() to extract it

```
select  Reference,
        [Required] = substring(Reference, cs, ce - cs) 
                   + '-' 
                   + substring(Reference, ps, pe - ps)
from    tbl
        cross apply -- find start position
        (
            select  cs = charindex('course=', Reference) + len('course=')
        ) cs
        cross apply -- find end position
        (
            select  ce = charindex('&', Reference, cs)
        ) ce
        cross apply
        (
            select  ps = charindex('plan=', Reference) + len('plan=')
        ) ps
        cross apply
        (
            select  pe = charindex('&', Reference, ps)
        ) pe
```